# What is this format in javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, format

What is this format in javascript or typescript?
I couldn't find any info.

1. export type XXX<> **= |** true (`= |`)
2. **`$ReadOnly`** (meanings)
3. <{**`|` ... `|`**}>

```js
export type AttributeType<T, V> =
  | true
  | $ReadOnly<{|
      diff?: (arg1: T, arg2: T) => boolean,
      process?: (arg1: V) => T,
    |}>;
```

Comment: Where did you get this code snippet from? What does that source say about the snippet and its syntax? What resources do you have at your disposal (text-books, class-notes, teacher handouts, online tutorials or references, etc.) that could help you understand it?

Comment: `$ReadOnly` just looks like a generic type in Typescript.  The `|` are for making Union Types.  So the result looks like it returns either `true` or a read only of the passed type.

Comment: This code file is `facebook/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeTypes.js`

Comment: More info  ->  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html   and  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Comment: So .. is that same meanings?

<{| hello: string |}>
<{hello: string}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2, this format is for $ReadOnly(one of utility types in [flow](https://flow.org/en/)):

> the read-only version of a given object type T

You can get more info in https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly

For 3, you can find the format in exact object type syntax https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types. Example from it: `{| foo: string, bar: number |}`

Put them together, you can have `$ReadOnly<{| foo: string, bar: number |}>`. More over, I see the usage: `React.AbstractComponent<{||}>` in [facebook react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBoxInspectorContainer.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/LogBox/LogBoxInspectorContainer.js#L66)

Answer (score 0):

1. The code is a typescript.
2. The $ReadOnly Prefix is used to make a property read-only. Read-only members can be accessed outside the class, but their value cannot be changed. Since read-only members cannot be changed outside the class, they either need to be initialized at the declaration or initialized inside the class constructor.
3. The | part is making the rest as a union, so it only returns the true or read-only . In the read only return , the `diff` will be identified as  `boolean | undefined`; and `process` will be identified as  `type | undefined`; Since all values has a default value of undefined, the compiler won't complain that `process` or `diff` is not assigned.

Comment: Is it the same as this code? ------

export type AttributeType<T, V> = Readonly<{
  diff?: (arg1: T, arg2: T) => boolean,
  process?: (arg1: V) => T
}>;

Answer (score -1):

I found it...
Facebook use 'flow'. (no typescript)
https://flow.org/en/